# Twitter4j NumberFormatException

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm using some of Twitter4j examples in their Github repo, but whenever I'm trying to use any username, for instance to get the last tweet, using:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong("userName"));
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "userName"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
```

Apparently there is other ways to do the same task, but I wonder if anyone has a solution for this problem. Also I'm using `'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'`.

Comment: See http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joey pointed out `Long.parseLong("userName")` is the problem. 
 If you use `twitter.showStatus(an id)` you need the id of the tweet, not the user name. If you want the last tweet by an user you need to do this:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
User user = twitter.showUser(username); //username could be an String or a Long with the id of the user
Status status = user.getStatus();
```

And that's it

Answer (score 1):

`Long.parseLong("userName")` is the problem. You are trying to parse the string "userName" into a Long value which will not work.

I think you're looking for... `User.getID()` check the following link:

http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.2/index.html

See: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html for more examples.